# Load balancing between Spring Data and Cassandra not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

Cassandra was configured on three physically separated servers and grouped into one cluster. Clustering seems to be working fine.

But when I run spring boot I get a warning.

```
2022-01-20 13:04:13.440  WARN 23724 --- [     s1-admin-0] c.d.o.d.i.c.l.h.OptionalLocalDcHelper   :100 : [s1|default] You specified test-dc as the local DC, but some contact points are from a different DC: Node(endPoint=192.168.0.102:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=21d8ad8c)=null, Node(endPoint=192.168.0.101:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=2f1f57c7)=null; please provide the correct local DC, or check your contact points
```

Afterwards,When executing a query to DB in Spring Boot, if the connected server is down, you have to run the query to another server, but it doesn't work.

When I run the query in Spring Boot, I get the error message 'No node was available to execute the query'.

I tried running it with only one IP address in contact-points in application.yml , but the same error occurred when executing the query.

Why am I getting an error without sending a query to another server?

Why is my Cassandra server connected to Spring Boot not load balanced? Isn't that an automatically configured default setting?

Please help. please..

cassandra server nodetool status:

```
Datacenter: test-dc
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  192.168.0.100  520.1 MiB  256          ?       6415d7ea-f5b2-480e-97bf-05e77caac4e8  RAC1
UN  192.168.0.101  509.71 MiB  256          ?       258d9c7d-4344-4d6c-be44-b1d08a37e915  RAC1
UN  192.168.0.102  521.25 MiB  256          ?       c4b49189-7fe6-4ab2-9861-e31d3b942222  RAC1
```

spring application.yml:

```
spring:
  data:
    cassandra:
      contact-points:
       - 192.168.0.100
       - 192.168.0.101
       - 192.168.0.102
    port: 9042
    local-datacenter: test-dc
```

Answer (score 0):

This warning message indicates that the driver thinks your cluster is not configured correctly:

```
You specified test-dc as the local DC, but some contact points are from a different DC
```

Specifically, the driver thinks that node `192.168.0.102` doesn't belong to `test-dc` DC.

Interestingly the `nodetool status` output you posted doesn't include node `.102`:

```
UN  192.168.0.100  520.1 MiB  256          ?       6415d7ea-f5b2-480e-97bf-05e77caac4e8  RAC1
UN  192.168.0.101  509.71 MiB  256          ?       258d9c7d-4344-4d6c-be44-b1d08a37e915  RAC1
UN  192.168.0.100  521.25 MiB  256          ?       c4b49189-7fe6-4ab2-9861-e31d3b942222  RAC1
```

I'd suggest checking your cluster configuration and try again. Cheers!

Comment: Sorry.. There was a typo while editing the example. The text was corrected. Actually, the ip is set properly.